# center 2 pictures next each other inside row using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

How can I put the 2 app download links images in the middle of `class="row"`?

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4" style="text-align:right"><img     src="images/bear.png" alt="bear" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 first-row-second-column">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 class="col-xs-12"  style="text-align:center">Καλώς ήρθατε, στα </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 class="col-xs-12" style="text-align:center">Κάνε σήμερα τη συνδρομή σου και κέρδισε7 ΜΕΡΕΣ ΔΩΡΕΑΝ</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 class="col-xs-12"  style="text-align:center">Αν είσαι στην Ελλάδα στείλε τώρα SMS από το κινητό σου ZOU στο 54790 και μπες στον κόσμο των Ζουζουνιών.</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 class="col-xs-12"  style="text-align:center">Αν ζεις στο εξωτερικό κάνε την συνδρομή σου μέσα από την εφαρμογή.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div><img src="images/app_store_logo.png" alt="app_store_logo" /></div>
                <div><img src="images/google_play_logo.png" alt="google_play_logo" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try/apply `margin:auto; max-width:100%` to the `img` elements. I recommend you create an fiddle so we can inspect it

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a sample fiddle or something, I'm not certain how this will look, but I would guess this will give you what you want.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4" style="text-align:right"><img     src="images/bear.png" alt="bear" /></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 first-row-second-column">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 class="col-xs-12"  style="text-align:center">Καλώς ήρθατε, στα </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 class="col-xs-12" style="text-align:center">Κάνε σήμερα τη συνδρομή σου και κέρδισε7 ΜΕΡΕΣ ΔΩΡΕΑΝ</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 class="col-xs-12"  style="text-align:center">Αν είσαι στην Ελλάδα στείλε τώρα SMS από το κινητό σου ZOU στο 54790 και μπες στον κόσμο των Ζουζουνιών.</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 class="col-xs-12"  style="text-align:center">Αν ζεις στο εξωτερικό κάνε την συνδρομή σου μέσα από την εφαρμογή.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <img src="images/app_store_logo.png" alt="app_store_logo" />
                <img src="images/google_play_logo.png" alt="google_play_logo" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This should put the two images next to each other by removing the divs that contained them, and use bootstrap to make an empty column on the second row, to match the one above with the bear. If the images are too close, you may need to make a margin rule in your CSS file.

Comment: What about splitting the `.row` into 2 half-elements using the grid like `.row > .col-md-6 > img .col-md-6 > img` and then using `margin:auto; max-wdith:100%` for images?

Answer (score 0):

Add `.pull-right` to get the hard-right alignment
[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)